# What does the "Simulation Threads" setting in the fluid simulation do?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

I was just wondering what that setting below the bake button does. Anyone know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It controls how many system processing threads are used to calculate the simulation, if you have a multithreaded CPU

Comment: allows you to set a specific number of threads...otherwise, zero means "automatic" (it should use allo threads available on your system)

Comment: How do you even get that button there? I'm on 2.79 and I don't have any Simulation Threads control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adjusts how many threads are used to calculate the simulation, 0 means "automatic"

If you hover over the label:

> Override number of threads for the simulation, 0 is automatic